# Elasticsearch standalone JDBC river feeder missing main class

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I'm trying to setup the feeder following this instruction https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc#installation
I downloaded and unzipped the feeder
I don't quite understand this step:

> run script with a command that starts org.xbib.tools.JDBCImporter with the lib directory on the classpath

what am I suppposed to do?

if I try to run a sample script from bin I get:

```
Bad substitution
Error: Could not find or load main class org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.feeder.Runner
```

where do I get the java classes org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.feeder.Runner \
    org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.feeder.JDBCFeeder?

Comment: Which script did you modify and are you trying to run?

Comment: I'm trying to run the found.sh. I didn't modify it because I'm trying to get rid of the java error first

Comment: Are you hosted on found.no?

Comment: I changed ES_HOME to my es dir, but still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

figured out the solution
it was to set the installation folder in script (not the elasticsearch folder but the jdbc folder!)

```
#!/bin/bash
#JDBC Directory -> important, change accordingly!
export JDBC_IMPORTER_HOME=~/Downloads/elasticsearch-jdbc-1.6.0.0

bin=$JDBC_IMPORTER_HOME/bin
lib=$JDBC_IMPORTER_HOME/lib
echo '{

          ...
          ...

    }
}' | java \
       -cp "${lib}/*" \
       -Dlog4j.configurationFile=${bin}/log4j2.xml \
       org.xbib.tools.Runner \
       org.xbib.tools.JDBCImporter
```